# Is this function differentiable at $(1,0)$?

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be defined by $$f(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}[ll] (\left(\dfrac{\sin(x^2 + y^2 -1)}{x^2+y^2-1}, \cos(x^2 + y^2 -1)\right), & \mbox{if }x^2+y^2-1\neq0 \\ (1,1), & \mbox{if  }x^2+y^2-1=0\end{array} \right.$$
Is $f$ differentiable at $(1,0)$?

I've already proved that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,0)=(0,0)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,0)=(0,0)$. I know the next step is to prove the continuity of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, but I don't know how to deal with the limit of two variables with such complicated form like this. Could anyone advise? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you learned how to take limits of multi variable functions yet? This knowledge should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I think it's better to switch in polar coordinates so
$$\begin{cases}
x= \rho \cos \theta \\
y = \rho \sin \theta \\
\end{cases} $$
with $\rho \geq 0, \theta \in [0,2\pi) $. So what we have is
$$f(\rho, \theta) = \begin{cases}
\bigg(\frac{\sin (\rho^2-1)}{\rho^2-1}, \cos(\rho^2-1) \bigg) & \text{if }\rho \neq 1\\
(1,1) &\text{if } \rho =1 
\end{cases}$$

And now I think you should be able to solve. If need I can elaborate further, have a try!

---

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comment in $\Bbb R^2$ when we see things like $x^2+y^2$ is almost never a bad idea to try polar coordinates, use this as another weapon in your solving instruments!

Comment: I was thinking the same thing! Polar would b the way to go anytime we see $x^2+y^2$

Comment: +1 for slick answer!

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt Thanks your hints, so I need to check the continuity of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$ right? And if both of them are continuous at $(\rho=1,\theta=0)$, I can say $f$ is differentiable at $(x=1, y=0)$.

Comment: I think you got the point, do you understand why is this true?

Comment: Because $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \rho} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \rho}$?

Comment: Well to me is a little bit more clear thinking this way: let $\Phi$ be the coordinates change, $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism and above you prove that $f \circ \Phi\ $ is differentiable so $f =\Phi^{-1} \circ (f \circ \Phi\) $ is a composition of differentiable function hence differentiable